# How can I add hamburger to my website's mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to add a hamburger for mobile view of my website coding.

I tried with the help of w3 school but it's not working fine.

I will share my html and css code. I have added a hamburger icon just have to make it active.

Should I write code in separate JavaScript file or add any code here in my HTML?

I have tried adding hamburger from HTML CSS properties

HTML and CSS for the mobile view header:

```css
.mobheader {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.hamburger {
  font-size: 33px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobheader">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logomob.png" alt="logo"></a>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="dots">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want this hamburger to work in such a way it shows 3 menus on click

Comment: use bootstrap. check the link. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: But my project head is not accepting bootstrap only JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, I'm not understanding what's your problem because the code you already posted works, I just changed the color and the size in the code snippet. See and if your problem is other's just clarify what's your current problem.

**EDIT**

I find a codepen and added to the snippet to show you what you wanted.

Source: https://codepen.io/mranenko/pen/wevamj

```js
(function() {

  var hamburger = {
    navToggle: document.querySelector('.nav-toggle'),
    nav: document.querySelector('nav'),

    doToggle: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.navToggle.classList.toggle('expanded');
      this.nav.classList.toggle('expanded');
    }
  };

  hamburger.navToggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    hamburger.doToggle(e);
  });

}());
```

```css
/* imports */

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro");

/* colors */


/* variables */


/* mixins */


/* resets and base styles */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

html {
  background: #5634d1;
  color: white;
  font: normal 10px/1.42857 "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/* nav toggle */

.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  width: 3.6rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav-toggle:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.nav-toggle .nav-toggle-bar,
.nav-toggle .nav-toggle-bar::after,
.nav-toggle .nav-toggle-bar::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: white;
  content: '';
  height: 0.4rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-toggle .nav-toggle-bar {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.nav-toggle .nav-toggle-bar::after {
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}

.nav-toggle .nav-toggle-bar::before {
  margin-top: -0.8rem;
}

.nav-toggle.expanded .nav-toggle-bar {
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-toggle.expanded .nav-toggle-bar::after,
.nav-toggle.expanded .nav-toggle-bar::before {
  background: white;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.nav-toggle.expanded .nav-toggle-bar::after {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-toggle.expanded .nav-toggle-bar::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


/* nav */

.nav {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: left 0.5s ease;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
  background: #28dde0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  left: -20rem;
  padding: 6rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 20rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav.expanded {
  left: 0;
}

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-toggle">
  <div class="nav-toggle-bar"></div>
</div>
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If it's what you wanted mark the response as the correct please. Hope it helped you :) @KashifKhalid

Comment: The problem is I have added the hamburger but I don't know how to activate it. How will it start working. It is just a web icon. How to make it work so that when user clicks, it shows some links or menus.

Comment: Are you using only pure HTML and JS? @KashifKhalid

Comment: Yes HTML CSS and JavaScript

Comment: @KashifKhalid You need to create the div of the menu content you want to show and show it when the user clicks the hamburguer, you need to catch this action with JavaScript and change the class of the menu content. Example: https://codepen.io/mranenko/pen/wevamj

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the hamburger is an image:

```
<img src="img/hamburger.png" alt="hamburger"/>
```

You don't need the h1 tags for images, those are for headings (i.e text)

Also remember the "/" to close your img tags; your logo doesn't have one.

Comment: The problem is I have added the hamburger but I don't know how to activate it. How will it start working? It is just a web icon. How to make it work so that when the user clicks, it shows some links or menus.

Comment: You would first need to add it either as an icon or image, so it displays on the page. To display a menu like you want would require a lot further coding and it's not something we can explain here in a few sentences. I'd suggest getting your image visible first and then trying to sort your menu. Best of luck!

Comment: <div class="hamburger">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

Comment: Sorry, I understand now. 'Hamburger' is the 3 bar icon you are referring to. Maybe this page can help: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp